# Packaging a desktop application

Tags: mysql, c, packaging

I am developing a project for school and I am just wondering what are the best practices in regards to storing user information in a database. Also if I have a mysql database do I just include the .sql file containing the table scripts and include the mysql library in the makefile? I think I am on the right path but am having a hard time grasping the concept.  This isn't really a syntax issue but more of a system design issue.

I have a hard time finding information on packaging c applications on google. Whenever I try to search online it always points to c#.

I created a project and included the mysql library in the makefile and it works. I am just wondering if it will work if I send the file to another computer. I only have one and cant test it out.

Comment: You need an *installer* (e.g. MSI). Are you intending to bundle MySQL or is this an application that connects to a client-provided server?

Comment: It's worth noting that developing a desktop application in 2024 in C is highly unusual. C# is the more common path on Windows, and C++ with some kind of toolkit (e.g. QT) is also fairly common, though to be honest, most applications today end up being Electron-based.

Comment: The program I am in is focused on c. I'm not sure why but that's what they are teaching. I haven't gotten that far as far as determining if I want to bundle mysql or have it connect to a client-provided server. It seems like they want us to figure it out ourselves. I figured we would have to bundle mysql with the application. The only thing is if I do that, I would be worried about the size of the application.

Comment: If you are looking to bundle a simple SQL database with your application look for something like  SQLite database, which will be much smaller than MySQL (I dont know how this works with your C program).

Comment: MySQL has its own installer and is not easily bundled. You could always list it as a dependency and force people to install it, but then it needs to be configured, which can be difficult for inexperienced users. Prasad's mention of SQLite is something I'll second as it has no server, no additional setup implications. It's a library and works very well.